# express $\int(x^2ln(1+x))$ as a power series

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series

$\int(x^2ln(1+x))\,dx$

My work: $x^2ln(x+1)$ = $x^2\int\frac1{1+x}\,dx$ = $x^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kx^k$ = $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^{(k+2)}$$
Integrating gives: $$C+\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left(\frac{x^{k+3}}{k+3}\right)$$

However, my book is telling me it is $$C+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{x^{k+3}}{k(k+3)}\right)$$

Comment: You did not integrate, that is, you did not produce the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$.  So the first line is not right.

Comment: $ln(1+x)$ = $\int{1\over x+1}$

Comment: This is $\sum_1^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}$. Multiply by $x^2$ and integrate again.

Comment: Oh ok, I see it now.